# WebRTC: Force iceTransportType relay with coturn

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

I just set up a coturn server and managed to let my WebRTC based app use this TURN server to relay all traffic. I do this to hide the IP addresses of the peers in the WebRTC traffic.

In order to ensure that the IP addresses of my peers are always hidden, I would like to enforce that the iceTransportType always has to be "relay" when someone connects to my TURN server..

Is it possible to enforce this at the side of my coturn server, and if so, how would I enforce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enforcing this is only possible on the client. The TURN server has no control over any peer-to-peer path.

Comment: I see, but doesn't that allow malicious people to connect to your TURN server using "all" as iceTransportType.. which then exposes all external IP addresses of the peers? (which is what I'm trying to avoid for security reasons)